# Can not login on dockerized Airflow on M1

Tags: docker, macos, airflow

I have been trying to migrate the local dockerized airflow from Windows 11 to MacOS (M1 Silicon) for the last two days.

The problem I have is that although containers are running, I cannot log in to Airflow with localhost:8080. In Windows 11 everything works like a charm.

While digging I read that M1 does not work very effectively while dockerized although I hope I can me things work.

Below are the containers' statuses:

```
537543b6ebc9   dlh.azurecr.io/airflow-worker:v1      "/opt/bitnami/script…"   50 minutes ago   Up 12 seconds             8793/tcp                 yaml-local-airflow-worker-1-1
cd2f0804a125   dlh.azurecr.io/airflow-worker:v1      "/opt/bitnami/script…"   50 minutes ago   Up 13 seconds             8793/tcp                 yaml-local-airflow-worker-2-1
e1d79f6e1755   dlh.azurecr.io/airflow-scheduler:v1   "/opt/bitnami/script…"   50 minutes ago   Up 12 seconds                                      yaml-local-airflow-scheduler-1
1bc5f768195a   dlh.azurecr.io/airflow:v1             "/opt/bitnami/script…"   50 minutes ago   Up 13 seconds             0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   yaml-local-airflow-1
2cbb96a232c7   bitnami/postgresql:latest                           "/opt/bitnami/script…"   50 minutes ago   Up 19 seconds (healthy)   5432/tcp                 yaml-local-postgresql-1
a157072edc13   bitnami/redis:latest                                "/opt/bitnami/script…"   50 minutes ago   Up 19 seconds (healthy)   6379/tcp                 yaml-local-redis-1
```

and the yaml-file:

```
version: '2'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  volumes:
    - ../../airflow/dags/:/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags
    - ../../airflow/plugins/:/opt/bitnami/airflow/plugins
    - ../../airflow/config/:/opt/bitnami/airflow/config
    - ../../airflow/scripts/:/mnt/airflowdata/scripts
    - ../../airflow/variables/:/mnt/airflow/variables
    - ../../airflow/certs/:/mnt/airflowdata/certs
    - ../../airflow/python/requirements.txt:/bitnami/python/requirements.txt
  environment:
      AIRFLOW_EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
      AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_HOST: airflow
      AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_PORT_NUMBER: 8080
      AIRFLOW_LOAD_EXAMPLES: no
      AIRFLOW_SECRETS_BACKEND: "${AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND}"
  env_file:
    - .env
services:
  postgresql:
    image: 'bitnami/postgresql:latest'
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=airflow
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=airflowadmin
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=bitnami123@$$
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - BITNAMI_DEBUG=true
    volumes:
      - ../../../airflowdata/postgres/:/bitnami/postgresql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflowadmin"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
  redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - 'redis_data:/bitnami'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
  airflow-worker-1:
    <<: *airflow-common
    image: datalakehousepacr.azurecr.io/airflow-worker:v1
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
      postgresql:
        condition: service_healthy
      airflow:
        condition: "service_started"
  airflow-worker-2:
    <<: *airflow-common
    image: datalakehousepacr.azurecr.io/airflow-worker:v1
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
      postgresql:
        condition: service_healthy
      airflow:
        condition: "service_started"
  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    image: datalakehousepacr.azurecr.io/airflow-scheduler:v1
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
      postgresql:
        condition: service_healthy
      airflow:
        condition: "service_started"
  airflow:
    <<: *airflow-common
    image: datalakehousepacr.azurecr.io/airflow:v1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
      postgresql:
        condition: service_healthy
volumes:
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

FYI - In W11 I am able to set everything within 10-15 minutes so perhaps it's something with the MacOS environment. Yet, I believe it's all related to Bitnami's image because I did some testing and was able to establish a testing Airflow environment, hence still do not know where to problem is.

Comment: can you try to retrieve webserver container logs using  "docker-compose logs webserver"  it might show releevant errors/where is the issue? I'm  on  Intel cpu based Macbook  and Airflow works fine in docker-compose.